# Ruby Savon SOAP inspecting request object

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

Is there a way to inspect the request object before or after the request call?

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.endpoint = "https://testsoap.com/wsdlserver"
end

response = client.request do
  soap.body = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => { :xx => 3, :yy => 4} }
end
```

Basically, how can I see the xml post data that I am sending out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always use pp

```
require 'pp'
...
pp response
```

Obviously that doesn't work for *before* inspections. For that case I rely on the logging function of Savon.